# How do I pass parameter unordered on typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a constructor. I send some parameters. How do I pass the type variable without changing its location?

Constructor waits width variable but I want to send type variable

```
constructor(
   name: string,
   field: string,
   width: number = 0,
   type: string = '',
   ) {
   this.name = name;
   this.field = field;
   this.width = width;
   this.type = type;
}

public static create(name: string, field: string, type?: string) {
    const scpCol = new ScpColumn(name, field, type); // constructor waits width variable but I want to send type variable
    return scpCol;
}
```

Comment: may u can be more specific about "changing location" or even describe your problem. thx

Comment: @Atomzwieback  Hi, I edited. I should send width variable 'new ScpColumn(name, field, type);' on process. But I want to send type variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `undefined`, you can skip over a default-initialized argument and get its default value.

```
new ScpColumn(name, field, undefined, type);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right you should define your constructor like this:

```
  constructor(
   name: string,
   field: string,
   type: string = '',
   width?: number = 0,

   )
```

and invoke it as you wish